# Store locator for iOS using Google Maps

Tags: iphone, ios, google-api

I am looking to add a "store locator" to a simple iOS application.

The ideal situation is the following...

- A user will enter their zip code.
- The map will display the store locations within a radius of that zip code
- The locations will be stored a Google Places account (if easier, I don't mind if the locations are stored within the app code.)
- Results can be displayed on a map or list view, or both. (no preference)

Does anyone know how to do this? Or of a tutorial that I can follow?

Ive searched around for a while and I cannot find a decent tutorial to get this done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this:

1) Download your list of stores.

2) Ask them for the postal code/address and then geocode that to retrieve the longitude and latitude coordinates.

3) Display the long/lat on the map, as well as your stores.  They can then see what is nearest to them.

4) Since you have the stores downloaded, preferably with a long/lat for each store, you can then calculate the distance away to the store and order them in an ascending fashion in the list, thus showing the closest ones first.